# Setting work_mem in Postgres for specific queries

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, memory-management

I'm using a library that delegates to a JDBC driver for `PostgreSQL`, and some queries are very complex and require more memory. I don't want to set `work_mem` to something large for all queries, just this subset. The problem is that executing the following code results in an error:

```
// pseudo-code for what is happening
String sql = "set work_mem = 102400;";
sql += "SELECT * FROM expensive_query";

ResultSet rs = DatabaseDriver.execute(sql);
```

When I run this I get an error that:

```
set work_mem = 102400;
```

returns no results.

This works in `pgAdmin` because you can execute multiple queries at once. Is there a better way to do this or do I need to execute arbitrary SQL and then extract the result set I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea what `DatabaseDriver` does, but with "plain" JDBC you just need to do the following:

```
Statment stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute("set work_mem = 102400");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ...");
```

Comment: ... and `RESET work_mem;` afterwards. I also recommend `SET LOCAL work_mem` in the first place, that way if you forget to `RESET` it remains transaction-scoped at most.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that using [Batch Processing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm)