# Java Spring - setting work_mem in NamedQuery

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

So, there's this: [Setting work_mem in Postgres for specific queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367273/setting-work-mem-in-postgres-for-specific-queries)

I'm trying to figure out how to do that with a NamedQuery.

Something like this(just an example):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmailAddress", query = "select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
public class User {
}
```

But I want to add `SET LOCAL work_mem = '64M'` for instance, so that this one query can run with more memory. I can't find how to do that.

Comment: `@NamedQuery` is a JPA annotation, I doubt you'll be able to achieve this. Can this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339608/how-to-set-work-mem-in-hibernate-configuration-file ?

Comment: I think you want to look at this: https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator - it says you can use it to intercept all calls to JDBC objects, so  you could add code to check if it is the right query. then execute that "set work mem" against the statement that is about to be used for your query...

Comment: You could probably alse use a Spring AOP decorator around the specific method that will call the query you're interested in, and in the decorator get a hold of the current connection object and use to execute this "set work_mem" before letting the code continue the call...